# SVN merge just a directory add from a checkin (without directory contents)

Tags: svn, merge, directory

Am trying to merge (from a branch) a file in a directory that does not yet exist on trunk.  Here is the example:

Trunk (from which we branch)

```
/
/root1.txt
/foo/foo1.txt
```

Branch (after 2 checkins)

```
/
/root1.txt
/foo/foo1.txt
/bar/bar1.txt
/bar/bar2.txt
```

First checkin:

```
A  /bar
A  /bar/bar1.txt
```

Second checkin:

```
A  /bar/bar2.txt
```

Assuming the trunk hasn't changed, is it possible to get *only* /bar/bar2.txt into the trunk?  Here are the solutions I have tried already:

```
svn merge -rX:X+1 /path/to/branch/bar .  --> nothing gets merged here
svn merge -rX+1:X+2 /path/to/branch/bar .  --> pulls bar2.txt into the trunk but not within bar directory
svn merge -rX:X+1 /path/to/branch .      --> pulls both directory and bar1.txt into trunk

svn copy /path/to/branch/bar .           --> recursively copies directory bar into trunk

mkdir /path/to/trunk/bar
svn add bar
svn merge -rX+1:X+2 /path/to/branch/bar bar/
```

The final solution here *kind of* works.  It allows me to only pull in bar2.txt into the trunk and continue but when I try to reintegrate my branch back into trunk later, you then get tree conflicts on the directory (directory gets added in both places -> 'local add, incoming add upon merge').

I understand that if my team would do finer grain check ins - i.e. add the directory in a single commit and the files in another - then I could merge as I am trying to above.  Is that the only solution?

1. It seems like SVN allows you to merge individual files from a branch into the trunk so is it possible with individual dirctories (non-recursively)?
2. In the partial solution I found above, can I mark the directory in the branch as merged to the trunk independently of the other files that were checked in at the same time so that I don't get the tree conflict?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
svn merge http://url/to/trunk/bar http://url/to/branch/bar bar/
```

It's easier if you think of all merge commands as simply applying a diff.  Compare the output of `svn help merge` to `svn help diff` -- they're very similar. Once you have figured out the `svn diff` command that will produce exactly the changeset you need, apply that to the correct directory and you're set!

So in your case, what you need is the difference between bar/ on trunk and bar/ on the branch, applied to the local (trunk) version of bar.

**Edit**: and in the case where bar/ does not yet exist in trunk, a simple svn copy operation will do the trick:

```
svn copy http://url/to/branch/bar http://url/to/trunk/bar -m'merging new directory bar/'
```

(Note that the target is the svn repository itself, rather than the working copy.)

Comment: but how does this work if the directory 'bar' does not yet exist on the trunk - i.e. I need to figure out how to merge a single file from a directory on the branch when the directory doesn't yet exist in the trunk.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you committed the `A bar` in the same revision as `A bar/bar1.txt`.

I would revert to before the two commits. Then commit the `A bar` separately, then the `A bar/bar1.txt` then the `A bar/bar2.txt`. You should then be able to merge the desired individual revisions with the trunk.

**Update:** Maybe [this document](http://www.collab.net/community/subversion/articles/merge-info.html) will allow you to do what you want. Seems a bit hackish to me though.

> Mergeinfo, or more specifically the
>   versioned property svn:mergeinfo, is
>   the history of merges made into a
>   given file or directory.  This article
>   gives a detailed look at mergeinfo;
>   what it means and how it works.

Comment: I agree but it isn't that simple if the branch has moved along significantly since the initial addition took place.  I would have to roll back, do what you suggest, and then start re-applying subsequent checkins back on top of the branch.